# Access install.php if install.php is present, else index.php

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Before accessing my php script, user needs to access install.php and configure the script. The install.php will delete itself after completion. After install.php is deleted, user must be able to access index.php

What I have tried:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /myscript/
RewriteRule ^ install.php [E]
```

I am able to redirect the user to install.php but not to index.php if install.php is not present.

I dont know the RewriteCond to check if install.php is present:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /myscript/
RewriteCond ?? ??
RewriteRule ^ install.php [E]
```

Any help is appreciated. BTW I am not at all good with .htaccess configurations.

**UPDATE :**

Thank you for comments and replies. Yes I know that I can redirect through my php script like:

```
if(file_exists('install.php')){
     header('Location: http://'.$domain.'/install.php');
}
```

But can we do the same with .htaccess ?

Comment: You could instead load index.php (since that is what you'll be using 99% of the time) and check within that file if install.php is present. If it is, then `require( ... );` that.

Comment: Why would you want to do that in .htaccess? Just for the fun of it or do you have some special reason?

Comment: Many of the people installing your app will appreciate it if you do not make them do apache configuration, even through htaccess. Some will not have modrewrite enabled, some may not even have the ability to use htaccess.

Comment: Ok @ScottSaunders. Noted. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding this to an `.htaccess` file in the `myscript` folder:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/myscript/install.php -f
RewriteRule ^ install.php [L]
```

**Explanation**

- The condition checks if the file `install.php` exists in the `myscript` folder
- If the condition is met, the rule will rewrite any request (since the beginning of string anchor `^` will match any file) to `install.php`

Comment: FYI: added explanation. :)

Comment: `I had to select her answer right as she was first, she wrote . coz of my question` No mate, that makes no sense to me. You should pick an answer that works.

Comment: Truly you deserved it for providing a most complete answer

Comment: Thanks @ValentinMercier, you're a gentleman, and we truly had a mind-meld on that RewriteCond. :)

Answer (score 1):

For a pure `.htaccess` solution:

```
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/myscript/install.php -f
RewriteRule ^ /myscript/install.php [L]
```

Comment: Ha, nearly identical at the same time. :)

Comment: Thank you. Can you guys tell me difference between `.` and `^` ?

Comment: @Jigar `^` means beginning of the line. `.` means "match one character". So if you just go to `site.com/myscript`, `^` will always match, while `.` may not match.

Comment: Indeed rather use the `^` I just pasted your first rewrite rule as I was most focused on the RewrtieCond which was the question. For that I will up vote @zx81

Comment: Thanks @zx81, I had to select her answer right as she was first, she wrote `.` coz of my question. :)

Comment: @ValentinMercier you can edit your post. So that others can get proper answer. I will edit my question too. :)

Comment: Also the `E` flag makes no sense.

Comment: @Jigar Indeed use `L` for signifying that is the last rule.

Comment: @ValentinMercier I'll make it up to you next time.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `DirectoryIndex` to achieve what you want ([docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_dir.html#directoryindex)). Have this in the `.htaccess` in the root directory of the application.

```
DirectoryIndex install.php index.php

RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /myscript/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewrietRule . index.php [E]
```

If the user goes to the directory the application is installed in, e.g. `http://example.com/myscript/`, it will first try to load install.php, then if that does not exist, it will try to load index.php. If the user goes to `http://example.com/myscript/index.php`, you are out of luck, but it does not make sense to go to that url! If it is a concern to you, you are better of using romaneso's answer, loading index.php all the time and loading install.php from there if required.

Answer (score 0):

I would try to check with that method if the file exists

```
bool file_exists ( string $filename )
```

Comment: Thank you. But, that I know. Is it possible from .htaccess ?

Comment: i wouldn't do it in .htaccess, i would program it in php.

Comment: I would just check in the index.php- file if the install.php file exists, if yes the user is redicted to it. After passing the install.php- File, the file gets deleted.